# Float left causes image below to disappear (on mobile screen)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive, responsive-images

I'm using this wordpress theme called hypermarket.

I added this bunch of code:

```
#hypermarket-new-arrivals-products > h3:after {
    content: 'Pick a treat';
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px auto 40px;
}
```

All is good on desktop. However, when I resize the width of the screen and it resizes, the first product picture disappears.

It seems like `float: left;` is causing the problem.

Here are the screen shots to illustrate what I mean:

**On Desktop:**
[image: Desktop]

**When slightly re-sized:**
[image: After resize]

**On mobile screen:**
[image]

I also tried this (which didn't work):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
#hypermarket-content {
    padding-left:7%;
    padding-right:7%;
}
#hypermarket-new-arrivals-products > h3:after {
    content: 'Pick a treat';
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px auto 40px;
}
}
```

Comment: Try using col-md/sm/xs for smaller screens and if that don't work, then write a media for the screen size you are facing this issue.

Comment: May I see your whole code? (HTML, CSS)

Comment: The better option is to write media query, as you can specify in which dimension, it should be happened.Or try to use col-md-xs (In the case of small screen sizes). Else please put your code here.

Comment: That's all the code for this part of the website. I'm using a template, and this part was added in the "additional CSS" column. Also, I don't have any coding background. How do i write a media for the screen size i'm facing this issue? But why is it that if i take out "float: left;", there's no issue on mobile site?